# Opposite results from different modelling decisions in logistic regression

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I'm trying to test the significance of 2 independent variables (***b*** & ***c***) in a regression model, whose values depend on another independent variable ***a***. To make this easier to understand, let's say we're studying 5 different frogs which may or may not live in the area, and there are 100 areas under study. ***a*** is the number of types of frogs found in a particular area. The known number of natural enemies for all of them is ***b***, and the number of available sources of food is ***c***. For example, if in an area there are 2 types of frogs (***a*** = 2), type1 has 2 natural enemies and type2 has 1, then ***b*** = 3; type1 has 5 food sources available and type2 has 3, then ***c*** = 8 (row 4 in the dataset below)

The dataset looks like something like this:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 8 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 3 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 17 | 9 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

It is worth mentioning that ***a*** = 0 in almost half of the data collected and is heavily right skewed. I've fitted three regression models to study the correlation between ***a***, ***b***, ***c*** and the presence versus absence of mosquitoes (y) in an area, which is a binary dependent variable. The parameters and results of each logistic regression model are listed below.

regression model #1: because ***a*** is extremely right skewed, it's binarised as presence vs absence of frogs;  ***b*** and ***c*** are averaged (when a,b&c =/= 0) because the information about number of frogs is (more or less) given in ***a***. The regression model is something like this:
y =  β1 ***a***(binarised) +  β2 ***b***/***a*** + β3 ***c***/***a***.
Results: binarised ***a*** as well as ***b*** are highly significant (*p*-value <.001), while ***c*** is borderline significant (p-value = 0.059).

regression model #2: ***b*** and ***c*** are put into the regression model as they are, i.e., sums instead of averages, while ***a*** is omitted because the number information is present in ***b*** and ***c***. The regression model is something like this:
y =  γ1 ***b*** + γ2 ***c***.
Results: ***b*** is not significant at all (*p*-value = 0.9) and ***c*** is highly significant, which is opposite to the results from model #1.

regression model #3: in order to study the interactions between ***a*** and averaged ***b*** and between ***a*** and averaged ***c***, the model is fitted like this:
y =  δ1 ***a*** +  δ2 ***b***/***a*** + δ3 ***c***/***a*** + δ4 ***a***:***b***/***a*** + δ5 ***a***:***c***/***a***.
Results: ***a*** is highly significant, neither averaged ***b*** or ***c*** is significant (*p*-value >0.1); the interaction between ***a*** and averaged ***b*** is significant (*p*-value = 0.03) and the interaction between ***a*** and averaged ***c*** is borderline significant (*p*-value = 0.068).

I'm extremely confused by the results, especially the difference between model #1 and model #2, because I thought they were just different modelling specifications that mean the same thing, but it seems they are radically different from each other and I don't know which one to trust.

Comment: If a can sometimes be zero how did you calculate b/a or c/a?

Comment: In that case b and c would both be 0 and therefore the averages are just 0. I should have specified that b and c are only averaged when they're not 0, sorry

Comment: Is there any chance we can have a complete/reproducible example?  We might be able to sort through and answer the question without it, but it would definitely make things easier to be able to replicate the problem ourselves ...